# Mapping a list of object models onto another list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two object models that share some properties and a list of one type that I want to use to create a list of another type. For now, I have something like this (and it works):

```
List<ObjectA> TheListOfObjectsA = the result of some query;
List<ObjectB> TheListOfObjectsB = new List<ObjectB>();

foreach (ObjectA TheObjectA in TheListObjectsA)
{
   ObjectB TheObjectB = new ObjectB();

   TheObjectB.Prop1 = TheObjectA.Prop1;
   TheObjectB.Prop2 = TheObjectA.Prop2;

   TheListOfObjectsB.Add(TheObjectB);
}
```

I'm curious if and how I could rewrite this in a linq statement without the loop (even thought we know the linq statement will be executed as a loop).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
var TheListOfObjectsB  = TheListObjectsA.Select(a => new ObjectB() { Prop1  = a.Prop1, Prop2 = a.Prop2 }).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, nice and short! BTW, you should make an edit and add .ToList() at the end:)

Answer (score 12):

```
List<ObjectB> TheListOfObjectsB = TheListOfObjectsA
    .Select(t => new ObjectB {
        Prop1 = t.Prop1,
        Prop2 = t.Prop2,
    }).ToList();
```

You have to call the `ToList()` method to get a `List<ObjectB>`. Otherwise, you will get an `IEnumerable<ObjectB>`;

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: because `TheObjectA` doesn't exist in the context.

Comment: you aren't using `t` and what the heck is TheObjectB?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this.

```
var theListOfObjectsB = theListOfObjectsA
    .Select(t => new ObjectB{
        Prop1 = t.Prop1,
        Prop2 = t.Prop2,
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var output = listA.ConvertAll(new Converter<ObjectA, ObjectB>(ObjectAConverter));
```

and then define the converter:

```
public static ObjectB ObjectAConverter(ObjectA a)
{
    var b = new ObjectB();

    b.Prop1 = a.Prop1;
    b.Prop2 = a.Prop2;

    return b;
}
```

Doing it this way, and defining the converter method in a public place, means you can do this conversion any time without having to duplicate the logic.

For more brevity you could even declare the converter statically somewhere:

```
private static Converter<ObjectA, ObjectB> _converter =
    new Converter<ObjectA, ObjectB>(ObjectAConverter);
public static Converter<ObjectA, ObjectB> ObjectAConverter { get { return _converter; } }
```

and then call it like this:

```
var output = listA.ConvertAll(TypeName.ObjectAConverter);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should help...

```
var theListOfObjectsB  =  (from e in theListOfObjectsA  select new ObjectB{prop1 = e.prop1 ,prop2= e.prop2 }).ToList();
```